# Does Linux Mint use upstart or update-rc.d to manage init scripts?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, init

In Linux Mint 15 the `/etc/init.d/README` is copied from Debian and says to use `update-rc.d` to manage scripts. However, all the script comment headers reference Upstart throughout.

Does it make a difference which one I use? Is there a GUI (i.e., like YaST) to manage these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint 15 should be using upstart like Ubuntu. You can check with

```
apt policy upstart sysvinit
```

That command should show that `upstart` is installed but `sysvinit` is not.

As for a GUI, yes there is one, you can run it from a terminal with this command:

```
`services-admin`
```

It is also bound to be in the menus somewhere or other.